# Barplot to plot frequency of DNA in different sequence lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe `df` below read as `df<- read.table("WT1.txt", header= TRUE)`. I want to plot the histogram labelling A C G T frequency for each length value. Is there a better way to plot this?

`df`

```
 length      A      C      G       T
     17  95668  73186 162726  730847
     18 187013  88641 120631  334695
     19 146061 373719 152215  303973
     20 249897  73862 115441  343179
     21 219899  82356 109536  636704
     22 226368 101499 111974 1591106
     23 188187 112155  98002 1437280
```

Comment: histograms are for continuous random variables. Do you want a bar plot? What exactly do you want the output to look like? If you don't know what output you want, then this really isn't a programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. You can ask for help with statistical data visualization over at [stats.se] or a different stack exchange site.

Comment: Yes I think that was the confusion, I need a bar plot. Thanks

Comment: @MAPK I updated my answer with frequency plot

Comment: @MAPK did any of solutions solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could melt the data frame into long format by the variable `length` and plot a stacked bar plot with `ggplot2`:

```
df <- read.table(text=
    "length      A      C      G       T
     17  95668  73186 162726  730847
     18 187013  88641 120631  334695
     19 146061 373719 152215  303973
     20 249897  73862 115441  343179
     21 219899  82356 109536  636704
     22 226368 101499 111974 1591106
     23 188187 112155  98002 1437280", header=T)
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df, id.vars = "length")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=length, y=value, fill=variable), stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dplyr` to calculate frequency for each base and `ggplot2` to plot bar plot. I prefer using `stat = "identity", position = "dodge"` instead of only `stat = "identity"` as it gives better sense what data looks like.

```
library(tidyverse)

gather(df, Base, value, -length) %>%
    group_by(length) %>%
    mutate(frequency = value / sum(value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(factor(length), y = frequency, fill = Base))+
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge",
                 color = "black", width = 0.6) +
        labs(x = "Base pairs", 
             y = "Frequency",
             fill = "Base") +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
        theme_classic()
```

[image]